# How to use two arrays together in k-object tag in Kitsune?

Tags: arrays, frameworks, schema

We are calling every dynamic data under location's schema except business updates. Everything is fine except update-details page because, in update details page we have the k-object tag of updates.

When we are moving out from update-details page to any other page, where k-object tag is of location then the k-dl tag of with location is not accessible.

**For e.g.**

URLs before getting into update-details page.

*www.example.com/bhutan/about-us/k._id*

URL after getting into update-details page.

*www.example.com//about-us/*

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this question right, you want to access object in another array while you are navigating from one details page to another ?

In this case, Kitsune allows you to access any array in any page. Say you have a page with:

```
k-object="[[update in Business.updates]]"
```

in the same page you want to navigate to another page, which is details page of a product, then -

```
<a href="View('product-details.html.dl').setObject(Business.products[0])">Click Here</a>
```

Let me know if this answers your question, else do give me code examples for me to give a clearer answer.